# AUCtex missing from the emacs package list

Tags: macos, emacs, auctex

I'm trying to install Auctex on a Mac using the emacs package manager. AUCtex is available through GNU ELPA. My .emacs file is as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("elpa" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)
```

When I type M-x package-list , I can see a list of packages in the elope, Melba, and gnu archives. I can see packages like auctex-cluttex but I can not see the AUCtex package itself. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to add MELPA to the package repository just add `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))` in your init file. Remove the other two s-expressions, since GNU ELPA is added by default to the list. Other than that, I don't understand why you can't install auctex.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating the package content with the following command, then try to install the desired package again.

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
```

This informs Emacs about latest versions of all packages.

Comment: This did the trick. After doing this command, the auctex now shows up in my package list in Emacs. Thanks!